# Query Postgres JSON array for values in text

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

How would I query a JSON array column such as this for text within each of the array values and only return those rows that have them?

```
["Mr Smith","Ms Wellington","Mr Anderson"]
```

I've tried these but neither return results when I know they exist:

```
select * from people where names::jsonb ? 'Mr';
select * from people where names::jsonb @> 'Mr';
```

Comment: @McNets The `names` column is not `jsonb`...it is plain `json`.

Comment: Is there only one element by line?

Comment: Only one. It is a flat array of values only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this case you can cast the jsonb as text and use regular LIKE operator.

> ```
> create table test(data jsonb);
> insert into test values ('["Mr Smith","Ms Wellington","Mr Anderson"]'::jsonb);
> insert into test values ('["Md Smith","Ms Wellington","Md Anderson"]'::jsonb);
> insert into test values ('["Mg Smith","Ms Wellington","Mr Anderson"]'::jsonb);
>
> select *
> from   test
> where data::text like'%Mr%';
> ```
>
> ```
> | data                                         |
> | :------------------------------------------- |
> | ["Mr Smith", "Ms Wellington", "Mr Anderson"] |
> | ["Mg Smith", "Ms Wellington", "Mr Anderson"] |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f6f85db3bd1220b82e89839b42b15d40)*

Answer (score 0):

There is one general way to test array elements for conditions more complex then just equality:

```
select * from your_table
where (
  select
    bool_or(<condition on x>) -- for any element
    bool_and(<condition on x>) -- for all elements
  from
    unnest(array_column) as t(x) -- for regular arrays
    json_array_elements_text(array_column) as t(x) -- for JSON arrays
    jsonb_array_elements_text(array_column) as t(x) -- for JSONB arrays
  )
```

So for your case it could be

```
select * from people
where (
  select
    bool_or(x ilike 'Mr %')
  from
    json_array_elements_text(name) as t(x)
  )
```